# How do I properly iterate through a list of web elements in Selenium Webdriver using Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm testing a webpage that has a list of product articles. Inside these articles are item title, item price, stock availability tag and add to cart button.
What I'm trying to do is get a list of all the product articles by using By library and CSS_SELECTOR locator and then iterate through this list to find the stock availability tag and append these product articles to a list of available items.
After that I'd like to randomly choose a product from that list and click add to cart button.

For some reason I keep getting the same length of the two lists, the one that contains all items and the one that contains available items, even though these numbers are different if you check manually.

```
        all_items_on_page = self.browser.find_elements(*CataloguePageLocators.PRODUCT_POD_ARTICLE)
        print(f"Total number of items on page is {len(all_items_on_page)}")
        available_items = []
        for item in all_items_on_page:
            if self.is_element_present(*CataloguePageLocators.AVAILABLE_ITEM_TAG) is True:
                available_items.append(item)
        print(f"Total number of available items is {len(available_items)}")
        return available_items
```

The **is_element_present** function looks like this:

```
    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try:
            self.browser.find_element(how, what)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

I added the prints just to see if the lengths of those lists will be different, these lines don't really matter and will be omitted once the code is working.
I'm pretty sure it has to do with the **if** condition and the solution is very simple, but for now I don't seem to know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

`self.browser.find_element(how, what)` means you find the same element `*CataloguePageLocators.AVAILABLE_ITEM_TAG` each time through the for loop, so it does not work.

See this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/is_displayed-element-method-selenium-python/), conside using `element.is_displayed()` instead of the above sentense. In addition, note that `is_displayed()` **returns a boolean value True or False**, no need to catch `Exception`.